# Python - Guess the number with try/except

Tags: python, try-except

Hi i'm new in python and i searched for some mini challenges to practice and learn more, now i'm doing a 'Guess the number' script, it worked but now i want to add to it a try/except block when the user enters not an integer, this is the code i have now:

```
from random import *
print('Guess the number')

def check_correct(u_guess, num):
    while True:
        if u_guess < num:
            print('Guess is high!')
            while True:
                try:
                    u_guess = int(input('What number do you think is? (Between 1 and 5): '))
                except ValueError:
                    print('Invalid number try again!')
        elif u_guess > num:
            print('Guess is low!')
            while True:
                try:
                    u_guess = int(input('What number do you think is? (Between 1 and 5): '))
                except ValueError:
                    print('Invalid number try again!')
        elif u_guess == num:
            print('You got it!')
            break

def guess():
    num = randint(1, 5)
    u_guess = None
    while u_guess == None:
        try:
            u_guess = int(input('What number do you think is? (Between 1 and 5): '))
            check_correct(u_guess, num)
        except ValueError:
            print('Invalid number try again!')
guess()
```

And this is the output i have:

```
$ python Project2.py

    Guess the number
    What number do you think is? (Between 1 and 5): 1
    Guess is high!
    What number do you think is? (Between 1 and 5): 2
    What number do you think is? (Between 1 and 5): 2
    What number do you think is? (Between 1 and 5):
    Invalid number try again!
    What number do you think is? (Between 1 and 5): Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "Project2.py", line 35, in <module>
        guess()
      File "Project2.py", line 31, in guess
        check_correct(u_guess, num)
      File "Project2.py", line 11, in check_correct
        u_guess = int(input('What number do you think is? (Between 1 and 5): '))
    EOFError
```

Comment: You are not using your input, but instead again ask for input. That's a mistake. Just fall out of your function and let the outer while loop do the work.

Comment: As written, you never use `break` to get out of the infinite retry loop. Whether an exception is raised or not, you go back tot he top of that loop.

Comment: But as deets points out, `check_correct` is doing far too much. It should check the value, output a description of whether the guess is too high or too low, then return True or False. `guess` is the only function that should actually be taking user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing `check_correct` should do is return True if the guess is correct, and False otherwise. It can also output a message describing the result of the comparison.

```
import random  # Never use from <whatever import *
print('Guess the number')

def check_correct(u_guess, num):
    if u_guess < num:           # You had the roles of u_guess and num reversed
        print('Guess is low!')
        return False
    elif u_guess > num:
        print('Guess is high')
        return False
    else:  # u_guess == num
        print('You got it!')
        return True
```

`guess` handles all user input, calling `check_correct` to determine if
the outer loop should terminate. The inner loop continues until `int(uguess)` does *not* raise an exception.

```
def guess():
    num = random.randint(1, 5)
    while True:
        while True:
            u_guess = input('What number do you think it is? (Between 1 and 5)')
            try:
                u_guess = int(u_guess)
                break
            except ValueError:
                print('Invalid number, try again!')
        if check_correct(u_guess, num):
            break

guess()
```